# Using Autocomplete Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working with ReactJS and NodeJS. I want to use Matrial UI's Auto Complete , but I have difficulties

So,  I have an array of String with lastname and email, like this :

```
for(let i= 0; i<response.data.length; i++){                                    
    tabAutocomplete.push(response.data[i].lastname + " " + response.data[i].email)                              
}
```

And I have the Autocomplete :

```
<AutoComplete
                floatingLabelText="Recherchez l'utilisateur"
                filter={AutoComplete.fuzzyFilter}             
                dataSource = {tabAutocomplete}
                maxSearchResults={5}
                onNewRequest = {this.onNewRequest}
    />
```

I would want to separate the lastname and email, by `dataSourceConfig` property like this :

```
                dataSource = {tabAutocomplete}
                dataSourceConfig = { lastname: 'lastname', email: 'email'}
    />
```

If it's possible, how can I do this ?
Thank you

Comment: You question is un clear. What difficulties are you facing? What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what issue are you facing. But from your code what I understand is that you want to show a dropdown with last name upon user search and you need an email of the user listed in the dropdown. If this is what you want to achieve then please take a look at below yours updated code.

Datasourceconfig takes two keys i.e., text and value. text key is to show its value in the dropdown and value key is to used to get the value of selected item.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.handleUpdateInput = this.handleUpdateInput.bind(this);
}

const dataSourceConfig = {
  text: 'lastname',
  value: 'email',
};

for(let i= 0; i<response.data.length; i++){                                    
    tabAutocomplete.push({ lastname: response.data[i].lastname, email: response.data[i].email }) 
} 
handleUpdateInput(searchText, tabAutocomplete, params){
  console.log("SearchText value: ", searchText) //here you will get searched text
  console.log("tabAutocomplete: ", tabAutocomplete) // here you will get your tabAutocomplete object
  console.log("Params: ", params)
}

<AutoComplete
    floatingLabelText="Recherchez l'utilisateur"
    filter={AutoComplete.fuzzyFilter}             
    dataSource = {tabAutocomplete}
    dataSourceConfig={dataSourceConfig}
    maxSearchResults={5}
    onNewRequest = {this.onNewRequest}
    onUpdateInput={this.handleUpdateInput}
/>
```

Comment: @hermadri Dasari , thank you for your answer. 
I understand the dataSourceConfig, but how can I exploit the value ? 
I would want to get the value in the sataSourceConfig

Comment: Updated my answer please check. To get value you can use onUpdateInput prop to AutoComplete component. You have to pass a handler function to onUpdateInput prop to get the value, tabAutocomplete, params. Check  this.handleUpdateInput function in my answer for more details. I hope this is what you are looking for